# Processing server not populating segments table

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, processing

We have an *8.1 update-2* **processing instance** configured as per [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_processing_server)

For some reason the segments tables are empty and even if I run the RedeployMarketingData admin page, nothing will be written. Thus Experience Analytics doesn't show any stats.

I noticed that if I activate the following config files on the processing instance, the segments table is populated immediately:

- ExperienceAnalytics\Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.config
- Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config
- Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.config

But this leads to other issues when rebuilding the database.
How does a processing instance need to be configured in order to correctly process segments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making sure the following configs were enabled on the processing instance made it work correctly:

- App_Config\Include\ExperienceAnalytics\Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.config
- App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config
- App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.config
- App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.config
- App_Config\Include\Sitecore.MarketingProcessingRole.config